# How to fix a question?

Tags: discussion

About a year ago, after reading the FAQs, I'd posted a question ([link](https://serverfault.com/questions/665191/whitelist-elastic-load-balancer-based-on-ip)) here.

Apparently it wasn't a very good question because it got closed shortly thereafter. The reason was that it didn't *"demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices*".

Well, In my own view it was a question with an interesting core and apparently other people found it helpful because of the useful answer and upvotes over time. This led me to believe it *could be fixed* to meet the question standards and add something to the list of good questions of this site.

So today, excited to improve a community, I flagged it in need of a moderator's attention explaining my situation:

> This question was closed a long time ago, because "Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices." I can't really identify with that reason, plus after all of those initial downvotes it has received upvotes over time and there is an interesting discussion and a +3 accepted answer on it. What else has to occur to make this a good question?
>   – Maneating Koala

Answer:

> **declined** - votes and answers don't matter. You are trying to do something your tool is not designed to do, so I agree with the close votes.

This came with an additional -1 on my question. But of course I'm not so familiar on this SE site, and like the moderator specifies in [his answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/8561/209489), I'm not supposed t use flags for that.

I just don't agree on that it's relevant whether someone thinks it should be closed because I'm using a tool wrong, instead of commenting on my question.

To sum up, I think I have a potential "good" question here, but I don't know if I'm totally misjudging this. If I'm not, does anyone have any tips how I can improve this question to make it go in the review queue?

Comment: Like @Sven told, you just have to click "edit", to edit your question and it will be automatically be in the review queue after. Nothing more to do. Flagging a moderator is more for urgency (like a spam or a insult) (and you don't see other option to cast a close vote, as you are to low on point)

Answer (score 9):

If you can see a way to improve the question so it fixes the problems that lead to it's closure, you have to edit the question first to actually fix it. If that's done, it will be inserted into a review queue so other people get to see it and can decide if they want to vote to reopen. You could also flag for mod attention *after* you edit it, but not before. Also, a flag is not the place to ask for advice on how to fix a question - that's what meta is for.

I interpreted the flag as a request to reopen the (unedited, original) question based on the fact that it has an answer and votes. These really don't matter if a question is closed - either it's a topical, good question or it's not and if enough people agree that a question shouldn't have been closed, they always could vote to reopen together with an upvote.

Comment: You are right about me abusing a flag for this reason. I did not realise this very well until I read this. This has made me edit my meta question. However, the rest of my question still stands.

I'd like to upvote your remarks, but it is not an answer to my question, more like a comment on part of it.

Comment: @Maneating Keep in mind that Meta is a little bit different. This *is* a place for discussion (unlike the main site), and it's perfectly fine for people to comment on whichever part of the meta topic they feel most inclined to. Not everyone is going to want to provide specific advice on how to make a specific SF question better. Upvote anything that seems helpful, accept an answer if it got you where you wanted to go.